# SQLConnection not part of System.Data.SqlClient in VS 2019?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using Visual Studio 2019, C#, and added

```
Using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

When I use the following code:

```
SqlConnection cnn;
```

I get the error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1069  The type name 'SqlConnection' could not be found in the
> namespace 'System.Data.SqlClient'. This type has been forwarded to
> assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.6.1.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' Consider adding a reference to that
> assembly

Is the SqlConnection type no longer part of the Data SQLClient in Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: Did you choose .NET Core instead of .NET Framework? Maybe you could use the new version: [Introducing the new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/).

Comment: Or if you want to use System.Data.SqlClient, you can add it through the NuGet Package Manager.

Comment: Thanks Andrew ... that was the issue

Answer (score 9):

This all comes down to what packages you have installed; `SqlClient` is no longer part of `System.Data.Common`, so to use `System.Data.SqlClient` you would need a package reference to:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.1" />
```

However, it is recommended (when possible) to prefer the new

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="2.0.0" />
```

instead when possible; this is the replacement, but requires a different namespace (`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` instead of `System.Data.SqlClient`)

Answer (score 6):

If you in .net core 3.x, please use NuGet to get Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. Then call "using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;".

Step 1:

[image: Manage NuGet Packages for Solution]

Step 2:

[image: Install Microsoft.Data.SqlClient]

Answer (score 0):

you should use:
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

not:
using ***System***.Data.SqlClient;